# How to see all disabled interfaces in Juniper console?

Tags: switch, juniper, junos

How to see all disabled interfaces in Juniper console without looking through all of them?
I have a Juniper EX4500 switch with JunOS 11.4R1.6 and all 48 ports are filled, so there are 96 interfaces in total.

Some tests I do involve repeated disabling and enabling of many interfaces and in different combinations, so I want to be sure that I didn't forget some of them in the disabled state. Can this be done with some filter to see interfaces only with "disable" option? Or the only way is to scroll through all configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From operational mode:

> show interfaces | match "Administratively down"

Or you can view the configuration part:

```
> show configuration interfaces | match disable | display set
```

Hope it helps!